# how i can name all my objectes in array of objectes with Jtextfield

Tags: java, user-interface

https://i.stack.imgur.com/68ou3.png I have a class named `trader` and I have another class named `product`.
My task is:

> the trader should buy many products (an object array of class `product`)

Now I want the user to enter the name of the `product` in a `JTextField` (using something like `Product k=new Product();`)
I want the JTextField to find the corresponding object from the `product` objects (somehow using/implementing the `equals(k)` method) and stored in the array of objects he has bought (`product`) in the `trader` every time he adds a product this way.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: What do you mean by `I want the JTextField equal object(k)` ?

Comment: the textfield shoud name the object @user3437460

Comment: or the user should enter the object name form textfield or any thing else in GUI  @user3437460

Comment: @IbrahimRayis, is the user supposed to be creating a new object name?  Looking up one that already exists?  Java doesn't really let you do much of anything with "object names" like you're trying to do.

Comment: no idont wona rename the object ,i want to create anew object using GUI @Louis Wasserman

Comment: hhhhh, please help me am beginner @user3437460

Comment: @IbrahimRayis, if you want the user to write `k` in the text field, and then for your program to declare a new variable named `k` in the class, that's not a thing you can do.  You can't dynamically name variables.  You can have a `Map<String, Product>` and you can do `map.put("k", new Product())`, though.

Comment: @IbrahimRayis Do you expect the full codes, or do you already have knowledge on Java GUI such as Swing? If you have no knowledge on Java GUI, I will advise you read up abit first. :-P

Comment: Sounds like what you really need is a JTable (or even a JList depending on what you want to achieve)

Comment: i dont know how (Map<String, Product>) work put here bit of what i really wonna do

Comment: @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(!(e.getSource()==editproduct )) {
      
 void  ssetproductname(){

Comment: //          Acount is class and  am in tarder class
            //    take the txefield input and tranfer it to string (k)        
      String k=tname.getText();

Comment: //  put the string in the name plase
      Acount (k)=new Acount(); 

 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect the user to enter the variable name of an object to the JTextField and add that object accordingly. Even if you can do it by reflection, it is not to be used in that manner.

You can perhaps create a `Product` class with a `name` attribute within the `Product` class:

```
class Product
{
    private String name;
    //Your other attributes here..

    public Product(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

As the user enters the name of the product into the textfield and click the button, you can add the product according to its name as such:

```
@Override
actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    traderList.add(new Product(txtProduct.getText()));
}
```

The traderList can be an arrayList which stores various products. You may also add some checks on the product name before adding them to the list.

Comment: thanks and sorry for The delay i add apic explains what am tiring to do @user3437460

Comment: @IbrahimRayis I saw the image you uploaded. Why don't you use a list or arrayList but using fixed size arrays? If you use a list, you do not have to painstakingly keep track of the count. Your codes will be a lot shorter, readable and maintainable as well.

Comment: ok thanks again for helping beginner like me wish me luck @user3437460